# How do you perform a state query in a unit test?

Tags: rust, storage, query

In a custom *Substrate* pallet unit test, I need to get a list of governance proposals using the chain state.  I have used *Polkadot JS* to query state before but not from within a *Substrate* unit test in *Rust*.

Do I need to use a mock?  I think I have to create to create the encoded key from the module and method names.  This is probably way off but here's what I've come up with:

```
let key = twox_128("Collective") + twox_128("CouncilProposals");
let encoded_key = scale_encode(key);

let storage_key = blake2_128_concat(encoded_key);
let proposals = state_getStorage(storage_key);
```

What's the correct way to do it?  I need an example.

Comment: "using the chain state" what kind of chain? Do you mean a live chain like Polkadot or just the state of your test?

Comment: I found a better and different method for the unit test which was to call Council::function directly.

Comment: Yea, that is the way its supposed to be done :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at how it is done in the [Nicks pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/nicks/src/lib.rs#L345).

In short, you are first filling the storage with existing runtime calls and then checking the storage whether these calls succeeded.